# MATLAB - get angle between arrays of points

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, angle

For the sake of illumination analysis, based on [this document](http://hilandtom.com/tombotterill/Botterill-Mills-Green-3DimPVT2012.pdf), I am trying to determine three things for an array of lights and a series of points on a solid surface:

(Image key: big blue points are lights with illumination direction shown, small points are the points on my surface)

- 1) The distances between each of the lights and each of the points,
- 2) the angles between the direction each light is facing and the normal vectors of all of the points:

[image: normal-normal]

Note in this image I have replicated the normal vector and moved it to more clearly show the angle.

- 3) the angles between the direction each light is facing, and the vector from that light to all of the points on the solid:

[image: normal-point]

Originally I had nested `for` loops iterating through all of the lights and points on the solid, but am now doing my best to do it in true MATLAB style with matrices:

I have found the distances between all the points with the `pdist2` function, but have not managed to find a similar method to find the angles between the lights and all the points, nor the lights and the normal vectors of the points. I would prefer to do this with matrix methods rather than with iteration as I have been using.

Considering I have data set out, where each column of `Lmat` has my `x,y,z` position vectors of my lights; `Dmat` gives `x,y,z` directions of each light, thus the combination of each row from both of these matrices fully define the light and the direction it is facing. Similarly, `Omega` and `nmat` do the same for the points on the surface.

I am fairly sure that to get angles I want to do something along the lines of:

```
distMatrix = pdist2(Omega, Lmat);

LmatNew = zeros(numPoints, numLights, 3);
DmatNew = zeros(numPoints, numLights, 3);
OmegaNew = zeros(numPoints, numLights, 3);
nmatNew = zeros(numPoints, numLights, 3);
for i = 1:numLights
    LmatNew(:,i,1) = Lmat(i,1);
    LmatNew(:,i,2) = Lmat(i,2);
    LmatNew(:,i,3) = Lmat(i,3);

    DmatNew(:,i,1) = Dmat(i,1);
    DmatNew(:,i,2) = Dmat(i,2);
    DmatNew(:,i,3) = Dmat(i,3);
end

for j = 1:numPoints
    OmegaNew(j,:,1) = Omega(j,1);
    OmegaNew(j,:,2) = Omega(j,2);
    OmegaNew(j,:,3) = Omega(j,3);

    DmatNew(:,i,1) = Dmat(i,1);
    DmatNew(:,i,2) = Dmat(i,2);
    DmatNew(:,i,3) = Dmat(i,3);
end


angleMatrix = -dot(LmatNew-OmegaNew, DmatNew, 3);
angleMatrix = atand(angleMatrix);

angleMatrix = angleMatrix.*(angleMatrix > 0);
```

But I am getting conceptually stuck trying to get my head around what to do after my dot product.

Am I on the right track? Is there an inbuilt angle equivalent of `pdist2` that I am overlooking?

Thanks all for your help, and sorry for the paint images!

Context: This image shows my lights (big blue points), the directions the lights are facing (little black traces), and my model.[image]

Comment: So did I get your question correctly: you are looking for an angle between dots? Does that even make sense?

Comment: @RobertStettler "Considering I have data set out, where each column of `Lmat` has my `x,y,z` position vectors of my lights; `Dmat` gives `x,y,z` directions of each light, thus the combination of each row from both of these matrices fully define the light and the direction it is facing. Similarly, `Omega` and `nmat` do the same for the points on the surface."

Comment: "I have found the distances between all the points with the pdist2 function, I have also found each of the angles between the directions the lights are facing and the but have not managed to find a similar method to find the angles between the points." – Something is missing in this sentence. Also, could you rephrase your question so it is more obvious what you're looking for? I for one can't tell what you already have and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @dasdingonesin Sorry, really poor proofreading on my part. Is it better now?

Comment: Much clearer now. "Considering I have data set out, where each column of Lmat has my x,y,z position vectors of my lights" – I think you meant to say each _row_ of the matrix is a position vector, at least that's what I assumed in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, haven't had a good look/implemented yet, but the only thing I can see that won't work is that the matrices are size nx3 and mx3, where m >> n (something like m = 1200, n = 13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101590-how-can-i-determine-the-angle-between-two-vectors-in-matlab), there is no built-in function to calculate the angle between vectors. However, you can use trigonometry to calculate the angles.

#### Inputs

Since you unfortunately didn't explain your input data in great detail, I'm going to assume that you have a matrix `Lmat` containing a location vector of a light source in each row and a matrix `Dmat` containing the directional vectors for the light sources, both of size *n*×3, where *n* is the number of light sources in your scene.

The matrices `Omega` and `Nmat` supposedly are of size *m*×3 and contain the location vectors and normal vectors of all *m* surface points. The desired result are the angles between all light direction vectors and surface normal vectors, of which there are *n*⋅*m*, and the angles between the light direction vectors and the vectors connecting the light to each point on the surface, of which there are *n*⋅*m* as well.

To get results for all combinations of light sources and surface points, the input matrices have to be repeated vertically:

```
Lmat  = repmat(Lmat,  size(Omega,1), 1);
Dmat  = repmat(Dmat,  size(Omega,1), 1);
Omega = repmat(Omega, size(Lmat,1),  1);
Nmat  = repmat(Nmat,  size(Lmat,1),  1);
```

#### Using the inner product / dot product

The definition of the inner product of two vectors is

[image: inner product]

where θ is the angle between the two vectors. Reordering the equation yields

[image: theta]

You can therefore calculate the angles between your directional vectors `Dmat` and your normal vectors `Nmat` like this:

```
normProd = sqrt(sum(Dmat.^2,2)).*sqrt(sum(Nmat.^2,2));
anglesInDegrees = acos(dot(Dmat.',Nmat.')' ./ normProd) * 180 / pi;
```

To calculate the angles between the light-to-point vectors and the directional vectors, just replace `Nmat` with `Omega - Lmat`.

#### Using the vector product / cross product

It has been [mentioned](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/151925) that the above method will have problems with accuracy for very small (θ ≈ 0°) or very large (θ ≈ 180°) angles. The suggested solution is calculating the angles using the cross product and the inner product.

The norm of the vector product of two vectors is

[image: vector product]

You can combine this with the above definition of the inner product to get

[image: tan of vectors]

which can obviously be reordered to this:

[image]

The corresponding MATLAB code looks like this:

```
normCross = sqrt(sum(cross(Dmat,Nmat,2).^2,2));
anglesInDegrees = atan2(normCross,dot(Dmat.',Nmat.')') * 180/pi;
```